# How do I regex for multiple items within a single string with c#?

Tags: c#, regex

My string is the following format:

```
"[Item1],[Item2],[Item3],..."
```

I want to be able to get item1, item2, item3, etc.

I am trying the following grep expression:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(query, @"\[(.*)\]?");
```

However, instead of match each item, it is getting `"item1][item2][..."`

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a [non-greedy quantifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx), like this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(query, @"\[(.*?)\]?");
```

Or a [character class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx) that excludes `]` characters, like this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(query, @"\[([^\]]*)\]?");
```

You can then access your matches just like this:

```
matches[0].Groups[1].Value // Item1
matches[1].Groups[1].Value // Item2
matches[2].Groups[1].Value // Item3
```